# why does mcount require frame pointer information?

Tags: linux-kernel, ftrace

There is mention in the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93uE_kWWQjs) at kernel recipes that `mcount` requires frame pointers while `__fentry__` does not. Can someone provide more detail on why the former needs frame pointers and how the latter avoids needing it?

Disassembling a trivial function `void handler(){}`
With -pg alone

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
1:      call        mcount
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

With -pg -mcount

```
1:      call        __fentry__
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: It's somewhat academic at this point, as Linux removed support for mcount based tracing in Linux 5.2. Commit which removed this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/562e14f72292249e52e6346a9e3a30be652b0cf6

Comment: I don't know why mcount required frame pointers, but as for `call __fentry__` - it is just a placeholder rather than an actual call. At startup, Linux replaces such placeholders with 5-byte nops on x86. When it is needed to enable Ftrace for a given function, Linux replaces the nops with an actual call to the trampoline function. So, `__fentry__` should not depend on frame pointers at all.

Comment: @Eugene, when tracing is enabled, just curious why is whatever replaces ```__fentry__``` referred to as trampoline in this case? Presumably it's a function call made from the start of the function that then returns to the original function, i.e. to the line ```push    rbp``` ?

Comment: @user3882729: Yes, you are right. When Ftrace is enabled jn x86, `call __fentry__` is replaced with a call to a trampoline function written in assembly, e.g. `ftrace_caller` or `ftrace_regs_caller` depending on the kernel configuration (see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.6/source/arch/x86/kernel/ftrace_64.S#L154). The trampoline saves the relevant registers, calls the ftrace handler (its address will be placed instead of `ftrace_stub`), restores the registers and returns to the original function.

Comment: So, I guess, it is called "a trampoline" because it helps launch the function needed by Ftrace.